# Correct punctuation for showing a character's confusion

Tags: style, formatting, punctuation

I'm trying to show that the narration (third person limited) is being interrupted by the character's thought process, and I'm not sure what punctuation is best for this situation.

So far, I've tried two approaches: dashes and parentheses. I'm not a huge fan of either. **Is there a better way? Alternatively, is there a rule about which mark to use?**

Here's an example:

**1. Single Dash:** The demon - she? He? gestured towards the supply wagons.

**2. Parentheses:** The demon (she? He?) gestured towards the supply wagons.

(The MC is meeting a pack of demons for the first time. She's not sure how to tell the two genders apart.)

Comment: Please enter your question on our weekly challenge.  It qualifies.  https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/tags-of-the-week-april-8-14-2019-punctuation-naming?cb=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Behold!  The Mighty Ellipses!

> The demon...she? he?...gestured towards the supply wagons.

Ultimately, it's a matter of personal style.  Dashes, parentheses, ellipses are all correct.

Part of the reason I prefer ellipses here is, as Amadeus points out, the gender ponderings aren't really an interruption.  It's an aside.  The narrator's mind is wandering.  Ellipses are great for that as they tend to indicate a pause in addition to a change of course.

Dashes also work great for asides, but don't indicate the same level of pause.  Note: use a full sized dash (aka a double or em dash) and not a hyphen.  Hyphens have other purposes.

Parentheses are okay, especially since you have the question marks to make it clear, but wouldn't be the choice that helps the reader with the flow and rhythm of the sentence.

Comment: And having capitalizing one but not the other is a bit jarring.

Comment: @Acccumulation I assumed that was a typo, which is why I changed it in my version of the example.

Comment: One disadvantage of ellipses is that they're not usually understood as coming in matched pairs, unlike dashes or (most obviously) parentheses.  Also, ellipses look like pauses, rather than changes of clause/tone/speaker.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen an em-dash referred to as a "double" dash, though I have seen hyphen pairs used where the limitations of the medium don't allow for a proper em-dash. To me, it would certainly look wrong to see a pair of hyphens in place of an em-dash in a printed book. One note, let's not forget about the em-dash's smaller cousin the en-dash, which fits right in the middle between the em-dash and the hyphen.

Comment: Ellipses here imply two pauses, which feels wrong for the flow of the sentence; the interjection is intended as an interruption to the stream of thought, which ought not require a pause.

Comment: @BittermanAndy If the author doesn't want two pauses, s/he can use just one.  Or different punctuation if the ellipsis pause is too long.  Pausing for different periods of time is a large part of what punctuation is for.

Comment: @aCVn I said "double" simply to echo what Amadeus said.  It's not a term I use either.  I just consider dash the long one and hyphen the short one.

Comment: I'm surprised this has so many upvotes, as I've always seen ellipses used this way as somewhat childish, certainly not something I'd use in any kind of writing I intend to publish. But there's no accounting for taste, I suppose.

Comment: @only_pro (mumble, mumble) Where'd that *roll eyes* emoji go?

Comment: @Cyn Do you have an *actual* response? My comment got an upvote, so I don't think I'm way off base here. As far as I know, using ellipses like you're suggesting is rather uncommon. I'm just trying to be helpful to anyone reading this answer since it stood out as weird to me.

Comment: @only_pro The question ended up on the Hot Network Questions list. That probably accounts for a fair bit of the traffic and votes on it and its answers.

Comment: *"I said "double" simply to echo what Amadeus said."* Yes, I realized that later. I still felt that my comment was worth keeping around, though.

Comment: @aCVn Your comment didn't bother me in the slightest.

Answer (score 5):

I use a double-dash, and specifically a double-dash (not an em dash), on both sides of the interruption.

> The demon -- he? she? -- gestured toward the supply wagons.

Although in your example, the interruption doesn't make sense; it would not make sense to say "The demon she gestured toward the supply wagons."

Comment: 1) A "double-dash" (two hyphens in a row, as you have typed) *is* an em-dash for a keyboard which cannot produce one. There isn't a separate mark of punctuation called a double-dash which has a different meaning or usage. 2) The interrupter showing confusion over gender would replace "She gestured." It's not meant to be in addition to what's there. The narrator doesn't know if the demon is a he or she, and so is confused about what pronoun to use.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, is this the first time the character... he? ... she? ... has debated on the gender of this demon? Then an ellipses could indicate that he/she has only just had the thought and it gave them pause. Honestly, you might want to think of it structurally instead. Putting it before the demon. It shows that your character is trying to use a pronoun and can't decide. It's a little weird to try and figure out a pronoun after already simply calling the creature "the demon"

He, or she?... The demon gestured towards the supply wagon.

I'm a little long winded in my writing so I would write it all out.